# Avoid importing empty line breaks as \n

Tags: r

Some of the fields of an csv file I'd like to import contain text followed by an empty line break or two. As a result, when using `read.csv2` to import thecsv file I obtain fields containing "[text] + \n".

I tried removing '\n' using `gsub("[\n]", "", x)` but this takes an awful lot of time. I was wondering whether I can simply avoid importing empty line breaks - then there will be no '\n' in my data. Using `strip.white=TRUE` does not work.

Any idea whether I can avoid importing empty line breaks?

The data saved in csv format, when opened with notepad, looks a bit like:

```
1;"text - text";1;Good
1;"text - text

";1;Good
2;"text - text";1;Good
2;"text - text";2;Good
3;"text - text";1;Good
```

My real dataset has much more columns. In many of the columns I have the '\n' problem.

To add some more info, this is how I import my data (in the example above I have no headers, but in reality I have headers):

```
read.csv2("data.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE, 
          blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
```

**Edit:** as an easy/quick R solution might not be at hand, I tackled my with problem with an Excel macro (I recorded a macro when applying the 1st procedure described in https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/03/remove-carriage-returns-excel/).

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us what these files look like?

Comment: Have you tried `blank.lines.skip` argument?

Comment: @docendodiscimus, yes, I tried that one but it does not work, because it will only delete rows that are entirely blank (i.e. when all fields of a row are blank).